# Session management when cookies are disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, cookies

If I have to implement cookie in dot net and user disables the cookie how can we achieve session management in cookies disable system

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sur you read the [faq]. Your question as it is currently is not fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Which is why many big sites have very long querystrings - all the user information is passed around in the querystring and validated on every visit to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can. But you have to do some readings about it and a few test to implement it. Basically you made the user send in `POST` or `GET` an unique ID everytime he gets to another page of your site, so you can identify the user.

Here some readings:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627029/Cookieless-Session-in-ASP-NET
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/using-cookie-less-session-in-Asp-Net/

I still haven't done it but i think you just need to edit your `web.config` file editing the `<sessionState>` value